# How to navigate to a page in a folder?

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have a problem with navigating to the JSF page when I move it into the folder, for example I have a page called ListOfUsers.xhtml which usually was kept in the root folder (I believe Web Pages folder is the root) and was working fine, page loaded while button was clicked. The code for the button looked like this:

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton action="ListOfUsers" value="Manage users" /><br/>
</h:form>
```

Now I have moved the file into Web Pages/users folder and it gives me FileNotFound exception or "Unable to find matching navigation case with from-view-id '/MainPage.xhtml' for action '../users/ListOfUsers' with outcome '../users/ListOfUsers'"
I was trying all combinations like /users/ListOfUsers, ../users/ListOfUsers and nothing seems to work. I realize that this is something really easy, but I cannot afford to waste anymore time on trying to resolve it, I will appreciate any attempt of help.

Comment: Try changing to `users/ListOfUsers` and make sure there is a *users* folder under the root and there is this *ListOfUsers.xhtml* file. By the way, your FacesServlet mapping in web.xml should be `*.xhtml` instead of `/faces/*`

Comment: So, `action="/users/ListOfUsers"` really didn't work? By the way, using POST for plain page-to-page navigation is a poor practice. Use `<h:button>` instead.