# Can't redirect to other page when clicking a commandButton in dialog

Tags: primefaces, xhtml

Hi guys I try to make a dialog, it's like when click submit the dialog will show up and if you click Ok it will redirect to other page but when I try click it its's doesnt work how to fixed it ??

this the code

```
<p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="successDialog" header="Info"
                    closable="false" appendTo="@(body)">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Save data berhasil" />
                        <center>
                            <p:commandButton value="Ok"
                                action="/prpk_paperless/master_prpk.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
                                onclick="PF('successDialog').hide()" immediate="true"/>
                        </center>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog> 



                <p:dialog modal="false" widgetVar="failedDialog" header="Info"
                    closable="false">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Save data failed" />
                        <center>
                            <p:commandButton value="Ok" action="#"
                                onclick="PF('failedDialog').hide()" />
                        </center>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
```

thank you..

Comment: Action has to be a bean function, not a url. Also in the 2nd dialog.

Comment: @Holger: No, it can be a 'page' as well... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435889/how-to-navigate-to-a-page-in-a-folder

Comment: Might not be best practice, but it should work

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Holgar I alredy try to changed it into bean function but it still isn't work

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

utils.java:

```
public static void RedirectToURL( final String url ) {
  FacesContext FC = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  try {
    FC.getExternalContext().redirect( url );
  } catch ( Exception e ) { /* do some useful */ }
  FC.responseComplete();
}
```

bean.java

```
public void function buttonOk() {
  RedirectToURL("/prpk_paperless/master_prpk.xhtml");
}
```

in xhtml:

```
<p:commandButton value="Ok" actionListener="#{bean.buttonOk()}" onclick="PF('successDialog').hide()"/>
```

Comment: Too complex solution for something that should just work!

Comment: Utils is reusable. One line in a bean an a shorter commandButton seems not very complex.

Comment: `#{bean.redirect('/prpk_paperless/master_prpk.xhtml'}` can work too, is reusable too, still it is a solution for something that should not be needed. That is (for me) by definition 'complex' ;-)